# Algorithm to find the points closest to a given set of 3D lines

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, computational-geometry

I need an algorithm that would solve the following problem: find the 3D points closest to a given set of 3D lines, each defined by a pair of points.

This is a figure that graphically shows the setup of this problem. In this case, it is visually clear that there are 2 "cluster" points.

[image]

I recognise that this is a clustering problem. I found [this](https://www.openu.ac.il/lists/mediaserver_documents/academic/cs/ClusteringOfLines.pdf) algorithm which is a k-median for lines in 2D. However, it finds a predefined number of points for lines in two dimensions. I found the mean-shift algorithm to have the properties I need, but for points, not lines. Maybe mean-shift could be extended for lines in 3D?

To summarise, the algorithm needs to:

- Find a set of 3D points that minimise the distances to a given set of lines (each line is defined by 2 points in 3D).
- Adaptively find the number of such points.

EDIT:

Because more people have suggested using the midpoints of the shortest distance between each pair of lines, then doing typical clustering for points, I would like to show some problems with this method.

While this method would work for a single cluster, for two clusters there would be a significant amount of points between them. This could be mitigated by only considering the the distances which are smaller than a certain number/ratio (say, the maximum distance divided by 100). However, this method would be very brittle, as it would only work for cases in which the cluster points have similar distances between them.

Ideally, the algorithm would be able to work with moving cluster points.

For the example shown above, plotting the midpoints between each pair of lines yields [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCeMu.png) figure, visually showing the problems I mentioned above.

Comment: Is it worth running different `k` number of points and seeing what the effect is on the error/number or points? Or is it true that it could be a large number of points?

Comment: The number of points can vary depending on the dataset, but not a lot (between 1 and, say, 10). Ideally, the algorithm would find the number of clusters on its own.

Comment: It might be simpler just to run k-means(medians?) for all `k=[1,10]` and pick the best.

Comment: I could not manage to find a k-means algorithm for lines in 3D. Do you know of any?

Comment: What does your dataset actually look like ? Do you have a table of slope coefficients and intercepts, and of the two endpoints of each line fragment?

Comment: The dataset only includes the coordinates of each endpoint, for each line.

Comment: This seems to be an XY question. You tell about clustering 3D lines, and address that by finding "closest points". I seriously wonder if this is the right approach.

Comment: Are the lines of finite extent ?

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear how you want to cluster lines. By what criterion?

You can certainly build a pairwise distance matrix and run almost any clustering algorithm (e.g., HAC, PAM, DBSCAN). The question then is what distance to use (minimum distance between the lines?).

Alternatively - because all your lines are simple - it is worth trying simply k-means clustering on (a) the concatenated points, with some ordering logic (point with smaller x goes first) or even more simply (b) the midpoint of each line.

In above example I am fairly optimistic that by clustering midpoints with k-means you will get close to the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried calculating the midpoint of the shortest distance between every pair of lines. While this would work quite well for one cluster, for two clusters there will be a significant number of points **between** them. This could be mitigated by only considering the distances which are smaller than a certain number/ratio. However, this solution would be very brittle, especially for cluster points which are closer together: it would result in a big lump of points encompassing both points.

Comment: What "midpoint of the shortest distance"? I was referring to reducing each line to one point, its midpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider this approach:

- For each pair of lines, find their [minimum distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213165/find-shortest-distance-between-lines-in-3d).
- Find the point along the shortest-path line segment between the pair of lines.
- This point geometrically describes the point of closest approach of this pair of lines
- Use all of those points generated from pairs of lines as input into a clustering algorithm of your choice
- Find the geometric center of each point-based cluster (your clustering algorith may be able to provide that directly, or you can find the [geometric median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median) of all points assigned to the cluster.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! While this could be a solution, the complexity of finding the minimum distance for **each pair of lines** skyrockets for large sets of lines. Ideally, an algorithm would work with the lines as directly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing some of the response here, one option is to compute the matrix of pair-wise distances. In the paper linked below, we used spectral clustering for this purpose. The advantage is that the number of clusters can be determined directly considering the eigen values of the distance matrix.

The biggest challenge in clustering 3D lines, as far as I understand, is that the triangular inequality does not apply. Thus a line may belong to 2 (or more) clusters even when these clusters are far from one another.

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8069424